# English to Arabic in Magento 2

Tags: knockout.js, magento2, translate

In magento knockoutjs, I have added text in html template I want to translate this lable from English to Arabic. I have updated it in ar_SA.csv file under i18n folder but it is not being updated on front end, so please suggest  solution for this. see below is my code

```
<div class="text-label" data-bind="i18n: 'Products Review'"></div>
```

Comment: I think you missed the code.

Comment: have you done static file deployment??